# Why I am not getting datatable in tabular format in reportviewer in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, rdlc, reportviewer

I am not getting datatable I created, in report viewer. I am getting report parameter in report viewer but not table. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Type-1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Column5", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("0.4", "1", "3.0","0.95-1.0-1.05", "Test1");
        dt.Rows.Add("7.0", "1", "3.0","1.68-1.76-1.85", "Test2");

        var reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource("Type-1", dt);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc";

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("RP_SrNo", _SrNo));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("RP_TestType", _TestType));
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("RP_Date", _Date));
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: You are give wrong name of Report. You can't put `.` in Report name. `Test_Report1.rdlc` try this insted of `Test.Report1.rdlc`

Comment: Its not name. It is Namespace.ReportName.rdlc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this with a Dataset. Follow the steps below
1. Add a new Dataset to your project.
2. Go to the Dataset and a new Datatable.
3. On the DataTable right click to add columns
4. Right on the columns to define the properties such dataTypes
5. Go to your report designer to add the Dataset you just created.
6. From the report Data panel right click on DataSet then Add DataSet.
7. Give you DataSet a name i.e DataSet1 -> Select datasource to the dataset you created earlier -> Available Datasets select the dataTable you added.
8. Design report -> Insert a table on your report and choose the data to be displayed.
9. Now your code should look like below.

```
//Report Source
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Test.Report1.rdlc";

//Set Parameters
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("RP_SrNo", _SrNo));
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("RP_TestType", _TestType));
reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("RP_Date", _Date));

//Prepare datasource (These should be the same columns as on step 3)
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Type-1");
dt.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Column4", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Column5", typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("0.4", "1", "3.0","0.95-1.0-1.05", "Test1");
dt.Rows.Add("7.0", "1", "3.0","1.68-1.76-1.85", "Test2");

//Add dataset as defined in step 7
var reportDataSource1 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks its working. But I need to create 18 tables in report. How can I do that using above. I tried to create 2nd table like above ,I am getting error - "The Value expression for the text box ‘Column1’ refers to the field ‘Column1’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.".

Comment: Add dataTables for the tables you want to add on the report. Then in the report designer under datasets add dataset for each of these DataTables. i.e Dataset2 select the datatable for the dataset and add it on the report. The report designer will let select which dataset to display.  Lastly add another reportDataSource e.g var reportDataSource2 = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dt2). dt2 is your new dataTable for another table.

Comment: Means I need to create dataset every time for each datatable. Is there any way to create single dataSet for all datatables?

Comment: The only datasets you need to be adding are the ones in the report designer in the report data pane. These are actually report data sources. Not actual dataset like the one you added to hold all you dataTables.

Comment: OK. But I need single dataset for all tables. Any ways I am going to mark this as answer for this question.